# Mac os partition corrupted

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, ntfs, boot-camp

i'm in big trouble. Here is my story:

1. i wanted to resize my bootcamp patition (i had windows 8.1)
2. i followd these steps https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5450324
3. i resized hfs+ partition from mac os x
4. i create a job to resize my windows partition ntfs after reboot with Mini Tool Partition
5. after reboot my windows system is corrupted and not loaded, mac os x doest exist in boot (option) menu. here is the output of **diskutil list** :

/dev/disk0

0: FDisk_partition_scheme *121,3 GB

1: Widows_LDM 86.3 GB - my mac os system should be here. i'm sure there was no formatting but i dont know why filesystem is changed (should be hfs+)

2: Windows_LDM 35.0 GB - my windows drive (should be ntfs)

please help to save all my photos and data!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it really looks like you formatted your OSX Drive.

Before you try repairing anything, I'd start of getting a complete image of the drive, preferrably with dd. Here's a pretty cool guide: [Click](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image)

Once you've done that, you can boot into windows and fire up [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It's pretty self explanatory and may be able to recover the lost partition. It also brings PhotoRec, which managed to recover 99% of my files when I was in a similar situation.

Good luck.